# How to write to firebase for a specific user?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm super new to firebase and I was looking at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth
I was able to do sign up and log in with firebase where I'm adding the user info into the authentication ->users. And then after you log in it redirects to a form. The form currently adds the data I want into the real-time database (I got that to work before I did the sign-up and log in) but my problem is that the data isn't attached/under the account it's logged in with. So right now It's just a bunch of random data and I don't know what data is whose. I looked around and haven't been able to find anything on how to make the two connect. Below I included my function for logging in and my function to update the database. Thank you for any help!

```
function loggingIn() {
  var notyf = new Notyf();
  console.log("Logging In");
  var email = document.getElementById("emailVal").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("passVal").value;
  console.log("Email: ", email, " Password: ", password);
  const promise = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) { // User is signed in.
      notyf.success('Logged in successfully');
      questionPage()
    } else {
      promise.catch(e => alert(e.message));
    }
  });
}

function setup(){
  //initialization and firebaseConfig is here as well
   dataMessage = firebase.database().ref('PersonData');
}
function writeUserData(activity, hours) {
  let newdataMessage = dataMessage.push();
  newdataMessage.set({
   funactivity: activity,
   sleep: hours
 });
}
```

The solution that I found is as followed:

```
function writeUserData(activity, hours) {
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  dataMessage = firebase.database().ref('PersonData/'+userId);
  let newdataMessage = dataMessage.push();
  newdataMessage.set({
   funactivity: activity,
   sleep: hours
   });
  }
```

Using firebase.auth().currentUser.uid; let me add the data to the current user.

Answer (score 0):

You can build out your post route to take in dynamic data, here's an example:

```
let postMessageRef = firebase.database().ref(`messages/${path}`);
```

in this case, you'd dynamically change the path to whatever the username is/whatever your criteria are

Then this does the actual post

```
postMessageRef
    .set({
        message: message,
        from: userName
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

**edit**
I'll read better next time...

```
  let userName = "placeholderToPreventDBWipes";

  const onAuthStateChanged = (user) => {
    userName = user;
  };


 ~~In this case I used useEffect, but you can throw this in your .then()~~
      useEffect(() => {
        const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
        return subscriber; //unsub @ unmount
      }, []);
```

Comment: This is for a messaging app so my route is messages/whatever but you can change that to something that makes sense for your application. The route is defined inside of the quotes that are nested within the parenthesis for the .ref.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have something like that but I'm missing the from: username, how do I get my user from my authentication user "database"(or from who is currently logged in). Thanks to your answer I see once I understand how to get the user that to separate by user it should be the same way I did it above with my newdataMessage.

Comment: There's a few different ways to do it, I'd recommend using useContext. Here's a link to the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: If my question helped you, I'd really appreciate you marking this as the solution <3

Comment: Is there any other way that's not using react?(I don't know react). Your answer helped a bit but It didn't answer my question :/  I'm sorry(The code you shared is sort of what I already have)

Comment: My bad, I'll edit my answer and hopefully that helps